# move argparse use into separate function

Tags: shell, environment-variables, fish

I have a question about the functionality of `argparse`. I use `argparse` for custom functions and it's great, but sometimes I'd like to move the use of `argparse` and supplemental code into a separate function and use it there to reduce boilerplate / visual noise.

This is a partial example of what I'd like to do:

```
function A

  set --local options ... # some definition.

  argparse_wrapper --name A $options -- $argv; or return 1

end
```

instead of

```
function A

  set --local options ... # some definition.

  argparse --name A $options -- $argv; or return 1

  # Code validating flags set by argparse in some way that argparse is unable to do,
  # i.e. validation that requires values from two flags (so f/flag!script would not
  # work).
  #
  # Or, changing flag names to names more appropriate inside the function.
  #
  # Other boilerplate related to options, but 
  # unrelated to the purpose of the function.
  #

end
```

But, I'm unable to set values inside of a function and transfer those values seamlessly to the caller. As in, `argparse` sets values in the outer scope (the function calling `argparse`), but I'm unable to do the same with a custom `argparse` wrapper of my own. At least, I'm unsure of how to do so if there is a clean way. In particular, `argparse` can set local variables in its outer scope, and I want to keep that functionality in the supposed `argparse` wrapper. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the person who designed and implemented `argparse`. The approach I recommend is the one you'll find in the *share/functions/fish_opt.fish* module. Execute the `argparse` in the function that implements the command. Define a helper function with the `--no-scope-shadowing` flag to give it direct access to the vars in the parent function. Then call that function to validate the args (or do whatever is needed) after `argparse` returns.

Comment: Ah, so a function declared with `--no-scope-shadowing` can manipulate variables in the outer scope? I might've misassumed that it could read them, but not write.